# How to do a grep regex search for single-quotes?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, pattern-matching

How do you use grep to do a text file search for a pattern like `ABC='123'`?

I'm currently using:

```
grep -rnwi some/path -e "ABC\s*=\s*[\'\"][^\'\"]+[\'\"]"
```

but this only finds text like `ABC="123"`. It misses any instances that use single-quotes. What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: for BRE, you would need to use `\+` or use the current regex with `-E` option to use ERE

Comment: @Sundeep `+` is not in BRE at all, but GNU grep BRE supports it as an extension.

Comment: @BenjaminW. since OP used `-r` I presumed GNU grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a PCRE. So, you need the `-P` flag. So, use this:

```
grep -rnwi some/path -P "ABC\s*=\s*[\'\"][^\'\"]+[\'\"]"
```

We don't need a `\\` for single quotes inside the character classes.  So, your regex can also be written as:

```
"ABC\s*=\s*['\"][^'\"]+['\"]"
```

Input file:

```
ABC="123"
ABC='123'
```

Run `grep` with your PCRE:

```
grep -P "ABC\s*=\s*['\"][^'\"]+['\"]" input.txt
```

Output:

```
ABC="123"
ABC='123'
```